# Expected a Realm with no or in-realm history, but found history type 3

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm trying to save my sync realm locally, but I'm receiving the crash error: **Expected a Realm with no or in-realm history, but found history type 3**

So, after successful anonymous login, I call **asyncOpen** like the code below

### Code Sample

```
`var config = app.currentUser!.configuration(partitionValue: "myValue")
    config.schemaVersion = 1
    config.objectTypes = [tracks_scheduled.self,
                                 tracks_scheduled_metadata.self,
                                 tracks_scheduled_playtime.self,
                                 transition.self,
                                 station.self]
    let username = "Example"
    config.fileURL = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL
    config.fileURL!.deleteLastPathComponent()
    config.fileURL!.appendPathComponent(username)
    config.fileURL!.appendPathExtension("realm")`
    
    `Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: config, callbackQueue: DispatchQueue.main) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let theRealm):
            let stations = theRealm.objects(station.self)
            try! theRealm.write {
                theRealm.add(stations)
            }
            let arrayStations = Array(stations)
            callback(arrayStations, nil)
        case .failure(let error):
            callback(nil, error)
        }
    }
    `
```

Ok, fine! It works perfectly!

But, when I go through an offline scenario, I found the issue.

How do I get my station list from offline? Look at the code below

### Code Sample

```
let username = "Example"
    var configuration = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration
    
    configuration.fileURL!.deleteLastPathComponent()
    configuration.fileURL!.appendPathComponent(username)
    configuration.fileURL!.appendPathExtension("realm")
    
    let realm = try! Realm(configuration: configuration) ~> brokes here
    
    let offlineStations = realm.objects(station.self)`
```

### Goals

I want to grab all offline data

### Expected Results

Getting error when trying to open realm file in offline mode

### Actual Results

`try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=2 "Unable to open a realm at path '/Users/fabriciomasiero/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/32F5028E-0A6A-4F6A-88F5-F01AEA5EC6BD/data/Containers/Data/Application/4C20900E-C42A-449D-8C0C-2DB19497B36D/Documents/Example.realm': Incompatible histories. Expected a Realm with no or in-realm history, but found history type 3 Path:Exception backtrace:`

### Version of Realm and Tooling

Realm framework version:  10.6

Realm Object Server version:?

Xcode version:  12.4

iOS/OSX version:  iOS 14.4

Dependency manager + version:  Cocoapods

Comment: That first code sample is not how to work with MongoDB Realm. It's actually a mix of how you *used* to open a Realm along with the new async of how you open *MongoDB Realm*. With MongoDB Realm sync, you do not have control of the filenames - they are generated automatically by MongoDB Realm and each file will correspond to a Realm Partition, as defined in the Realm Object Schema. Review the docs [Sync](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/examples/sync-changes-between-devices/#ios-sync-data). Also, with MongoDB Realm, there is no 'offline' vs 'online' so you don't need to 'grab offline data'